# X Axis label and tool tip Alignment While zooming in highstock(timeline chart)

Tags: highcharts

If you zoom in on the chart, then hover over any of the timeline you should be able to see the problem I'm facing. The tooltips seem to offset themselves, almost as if they're trying to show where they would be, facing this problem only on zooming.
Zooming the chart hovering over 07:10 time values are correct but see the x-axis label where its. i want to see both tool tip  and x-axis label(07:00) in same place .

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/jrEDT/4/`
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: So you need to feed chart with data with that values, for example: `[1368428867000,146.2345],[1368429174000,65.9934]` these two points are referring to 7:08 and 7:12, so you don't have 7:10 to show tooltip in that place.

Comment: My series values are in that format only, take value to zoom like 16.00 zoom this value up to you get x-axis labels(16.00,16.05,16.10)now see where its label and data point in tooltip ..

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but when I zoom to 16:00, labels on xAxis are proper (16:00, 16:05, 16:10) and tooltip show proper datapoints (16:02, 16:07, 16:12). If you want ticks in the same places as points are you need to write your own tickPositioner.